# Max cryo pod perks?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I finished one playthrough on normal and the max I attained were 19/28 cryo pod perks. The completionist in me would like to see 28/28 cryo pod perks.

Would higher difficulties have unlocked more cryo pod perks for me? Could NG+ help attain 28/28 cryo pod perks?

What are the maximum cryo pod perks that can be attained in one playthrough?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Patch 1.08 retroactively awarded Cryo Pod points based on AVP that had previously been gained past the pre-1.06 total.

---

Patch 1.06 changed the game so that the max AVP level is 29, allowing 28 Cryo Pod unlocks. This allows you to unlock all current Cryo Pods in one playthrough.

The previous answer is left below for those using 1.05 or earlier

---

Only 19 can be obtained in a playthrough (You start at Level 1 Andromeda Viability, and get 1 point per level up to level 20), and all your Cryo Pod unlocks are lost on NG+ (as well as your viability level being reset to 1).

The recent patch fixed the glitch that displayed negative AVP at level 20, which confirmed that 20 is the max Viability rank we can currently obtain. It is unknown at this point if Future DLC will increase this cap, or potentially award extra Cryo Pod points outside of Viability level.

Comment: It should be noted that there will be no DLC in the future, so it is likely that the level 20 cap will remain.

https://www.polygon.com/2017/8/19/16174510/mass-effect-andromeda-no-dlc-last-update

Answer (score -1):

I have unlocked all 28 perks, and by the end of the game I have 33 Cryo Pod points. With so many extra points I thought maybe the online aspect would unlock more perks, but clearly I didn't miss out on anything.

Comment: So many extra points i was thinkng maybe the online aspect unlock more perks. Clearly i didnt miss out on anything